# Bind a function defined in an anonymous object

Tags: javascript, binding, callback, sapui5

I'm writing a SAPUI5 application that have a `sap.m.Table` loaded at runtime. I want to use a `factory` method defined inside the controller (is this the best way?). To do this, after the aquiring of the model, I have to bind my table's aggregation (`items`) to that model:

```
tableSeason.bindAggregation("items", {
   path: "/results",
   factory: this.tableFactory
});
```

Sadly this piece of code doesn't work, becouse the function `tableFactory` have inner calls to `this`.

The `tableFactory`'s prototype is `tableFactory: function(sId, oContext){...}`.

I dont want to put the whole code inside the `tableFactory` function, can someone suggests a way to resolve this problem?

Thanks, 
Gabriele

Comment: this.tableFactory.bind(this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna attach the function to the factory:

```
this.tableFactory.bind(this)
```

If you want to the function be called immediately

```
this.tableFactory.call(this)

this.tableFactory.apply(this)
```